# Using Tableau Javascript API on Tableau Dashboard Loaded through aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, filtering, tableau-api

I have a non-public Tableau Dashboard that I load through aspx file, which supplies the required authentication, username and password, and allows the site visitor to view the tableau on the website, with the ticket it receives.

So, now, I want the Tableau to load on the website with filters already applied through the Javascript API.

Or, how can I use the "onFirstInteractive" option of the Javascript? The problem is I don't need to use the Javascript API to load the Tableau but just need it to apply filters on the Dashboard.

```
function tableauFilter (){
var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("viz2"); // Don't need this
var url = "https://public.tableau.com/views/Test_1228/Dashboard1" // Don't need this either
var options = {
onFirstInteractive : function(FilterName,Value){   //This is what I want to be able to use  
    activesheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to test this out myself for confidence, but I'm fairly sure that the Javascript API can only be used to apply filters to a dashboard that has been loaded using the Javascript API.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After surfing around for quite a while, finally found a work around to initialize the tableau inside the aspx file with jquery and ajax. 
The ticket was the tricky part because it changed every time the page loaded, once we were able to get the ticket value in a variable, we were able to load the tableau dashboard with the javascript API!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just modify the URL itself to include the parameter values as per your need?

[This](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/view-filters-url) and [this](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/embed_list.htm) may be of help.

Comment: Thank you for the links, although those weren't actually the answers I was looking for, they were helpful. 

In my case, the url modifying is not the best solution. The dashboard is huge with lots of users, everything's dynamic including the generated url.